# How do I insert data into database but with fixed characters in front in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I wish to know how to insert a data with fixed letters in front. For example, on this form I wish the `student` or `lecturer` ID to start with something fixed. So when I select user type student, the user id will be fixed to `ST` infront but after st it's free for the user to input whatever they. When I select user type lecturer, it will be fixed to `LE` in front. Right now the code is working fine but I just want the feature mentioned. This is the code for the student/lecturer id field.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="userID" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
        {{ __('Student/Lecturer ID') }}
    </label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="userID" type="text" 
               class="form-control @error('userID') is-invalid @enderror" name="userID"
               value="{{ old('userID') }}" required autocomplete="userID">

        @error('userID')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Insert form]

Comment: Does your user model have a type field which says if the user is a student or lecturer?

Comment: By user model, do you mean the User.php in the app folder?

Comment: This can be implemented from front or backend it depends on you, if you could post your backend code where you are saving data to DB then it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against prefixing your `user` `id` with anything. Doing so will most likely cause you problems at some point. When working with `relationships` for example, Laravel expects a `numeric` value. It is also more flexible.

Specifying different `user` `types` is a common scenario and can be achieved by defining a `type` field on your `user` model which can be used to identify your `user` `type`.

For example, in a `users` table migration file add a `type` column to the `users` table:

```
$table->string('type')->default('st');
```

This field will store the `type` value submitted from your registration form, or any other form where a `user` has their data managed.

Using the `type` field you can identify if a `user` is an `administrator/lecturer/student` by inspecting the value and perform any `user` `type` specific logic from there.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a script for that. here's a sample:

```
var idformat = 'ABC-E'+ currYear + getRecID(parseInt(rec_cnt)+1);
    
    $('#cust_001').val(idformat);
```

in this case, the input always starts with **ABC-E**.